# How do I solve the following error in MATLAB for "lsqnonlin" function

Tags: matlab, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem in MATLAB with `lsqnonlin` function. I have defined all my functions and solved all ordinary differential equations for parameter estimation. The question is why `lsqnonlin` is executing error in workspace. Here is my code:

```
%% Main script calls the solutions and gives the output
clc; clear;

%% Glucose Model

% Defining all the three known vectors
texp = [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 19 22 27 32 42 52 62 72 82 92 102 ...
    122 142 162 182];
Gexp = [92 350 287 251 240 216 211 205 196 192 172 163 142 124 105 92 84 ...
    77 82 81 82 82 85 90];
Iexp = [11 26 130 85 51 49 45 41 35 30 30 27 30 22 15 15 11 10 8 11 7 8 8 7];
Gexp = Gexp';  %Transpose Gexp

% Now using the least square method and non-linear optimization to get the
% final parameters
fparas = [0 92 11]; % Fixed parameters, X(0), Gb, Ib

% Initial values
p1 = 3.992e-2;  %p1 = Sg (approx. 0.03)
p2 = 0.200e-1;  %p2 = k3
p3 = 0.400e-4;  
Go = 0.287e3;
disp('----------GLUCOSE MODEL----------')
fprintf('Initial Values: \n')
fprintf('G(0) = %0.0f [mg.dL^-1]\np1 = %0.3e[min^-1]\np2 = %0.3f [min^-1]\n',Go,p1,p2)
fprintf('p3 = %0.1e\n\n',p3)

pinits = [p1;p2;p3;Go];  %Initial parameter vectors

%Calling the method
res = @(p) obj_fun(p,fparas,texp,Iexp,Gexp);

% Options for minimzation
opts = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Display','iter','TolFun',1e-6,...
    'TolX',1e-10,'MaxIter',500,'MaxFunEvals',1000);
opts.Algorithm = 'levenberg-marquardt';

% Solving the equation
[xOpt,~] = lsqnonlin(res,pinits,[],[],opts); %non linear least squares

% Calling (declaring) the function for getting the required values
%Functions must be defined and declared. 
% Variable parameters
x0(1) = xOpt(4);  %287.0000
p1 = xOpt(1);     %0.0399
p2 = xOpt(2);     %0.0200
p3 = xOpt(3);     %5.2058e-06 (approx. 0.05e-4 which is 0.1e-4)

% Fixed parameters
x0(2) = fparas(1);    %[287.0000,0]
Gb = fparas(2);       %92
lb = fparas(3);       %11

paras = [p1, Gb, p2, p3, lb];  %Vector form
x0 = x0'; %Transpose x0

% Calling the differential equation system
dGXdt = @(t,y) gluc_ins_sol(t,y,paras,texp,Iexp);

% Solving it using ode45
[t,sol] = ode45(dGXdt,[0 texp(end)],x0);  %interpolated time with interpolated glucose 
             %and interpolated time with interpolated interstitial insulin

G = sol(:,1); %First column of sol
X = sol(:,2); %Second column of sol

figure(1)
plot(t,G,'b','LineWidth',2)  %time by glucose level
xlabel('time [min]')
ylabel('glucose level [mg/dL]')
hold on
plot(texp,Gexp,'ro','LineWidth',2)%Experimental time by experimental glucose
legend('Model Simulation','Experimental Test Data') 
grid on
xlim([texp(1) texp(end)]) %limit of x axis from 0 to 182

figure(2)
plot(t,X,'b','LineWidth',2) %time by interstitial insulin
xlabel('time [min]')
ylabel('interstitial insulin [1/min]')
grid on
xlim([texp(1) texp(end)]) %limit of x axis from 0 to 1

fprintf('\nOptimized Values: \n')
fprintf('G(0) = %0.0f [mg.dL^-1]\np1 = %0.1e[min^-1]\np2 = %0.3f [min^-1]\n',x0(1),p1,p2)
fprintf('p3 = %0.1e\n\n',p3)

%% Insulin model
n = 0.257;
gamma = 0.0028;  %Pacini paper says to use 0.001
h = 92;   %initial for h is basal glucose level
Io = 351;

% Calling the solution
disp('----------INSULIN MODEL----------')
fprintf('Initial Values: \n')
fprintf('I(0) = %0.0f\nn = %0.3e\ngamma = %0.3f\n',Io,n,gamma)
fprintf('h = %0.1f\n\n',h)

% Calling the method
ress = @(pp) obj_fun_ins(pp,texp,Iexp,Gexp);
% Options for minimzation
opts = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Display','iter','TolFun',1e-6,...
    'TolX',1e-10,'MaxIter',500,'MaxFunEvals',1000);
opts.Algorithm = 'levenberg-marquardt';

% Solving the equation
[xOptt,ress] = lsqnonlin(ress,[n;gamma;h;Io],[],[],opts); %non linear least square

n = xOpt(1);      %0.2576
gamma = xOpt(2);  %0.0024
h = xOpt(3);      %92.0000
Io = xOpt(4);     %351.0000

fprintf('Optimized Values: \n')
fprintf('I(0) = %0.0f\nn = %0.3e\ngamma = %0.3f\n',Io,n,gamma)
fprintf('h = %0.1f\n\n',h)

%% Plotting the new model
% Calling ode
dI = @(t,I) insu_eqn(t,I,Gexp,xOpt(1:3),texp);

% Solving the equation
[t,I] = ode45(dI,[texp(1) texp(end)],xOpt(4)); %interpolated time with interpolated insulin

figure(3)
plot(t,I,'r','LineWidth',2) %time by insulin level
xlabel('Time [mins]')
ylabel('Insulin Level [\muU/ml]')
grid on

xlim([t(1) t(end)]) %limit of x axis from 0 to 182
```

And the following is the error I'm facing:

```
Undefined function 'insu_eqn' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in insu_model/@(t,I)insu_eqn(t,I,Gexp,paras(1:3),texp)


Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in insu_model (line 7)
[~,I] = ode45(dI,texp,paras(4));

Error in obj_fun_ins (line 5)
I = insu_model(texp,Gexp,paras);

Error in @(pp)obj_fun_ins(pp,texp,Iexp,Gexp)


Error in lsqnonlin (line 194)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn{3},xCurrent,varargin{:});

Error in Script_To_Run (line 108)
[xOptt,ress] = lsqnonlin(ress,[n;gamma;h;Io],[],[],opts); %non linear least square

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQNONLIN cannot continue.
```

Comment: well looks like `insu_eqn` does not exist, or is not on your path.

Comment: Yes I know. But what about this: Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQNONLIN cannot continue.

Comment: why would that error be unrelated to the fact that Matlab cannot find the function `insu_eqn`?

Comment: Because as it has to be, all programming languages move step by step, line by line of a program. if one line is incorrect or wrong in syntaxes, it will be stopped there.

Comment: No thats not what happens here. You first define a handle to a function `dI`, that does not execute the function `insu_eqn`. So only when `insu_eqn` has to be evaluated within `lsqnonlin`, this error pops up. Whats the output of `which insu_eqn`

Comment: But I used "lsqnonlin" function before "dI" handle. So You are saying that even I defined the insu_eqn function after lsqnonlin, It could still give me error?. Is that possible in all languages?